# Display all records in Crystal Reports if some parameters given and some is blank

Tags: crystal-reports

I am making a Crystal Report which has four parameters named `a` ,`b`, `c` and `d`.

Using these parameters, I want to fetch data from four columns named 'First' , 'Second', 'Third' and 'Fourth' which are from `rptData` table.

Now I want to load the report giving `a` and `b` parameters and keeping `c` and `d` parameters blank; intending that the report will filter the data using `a` and `b` parameters and all matching data from `Third` and `Fourth` will be loaded. In other words, if I would run query in SSMS it would be like this.

```
select * from dbo.rptData where First = 'a' and Second = 'b';
```

I am a beginner in Crystal Report. So i tried like this: from Report Menu->Selection Formulas->Record and saved it there:

```
if isnull({?a}) or {?a} = '' then true else
{rptData.First} like {?a}

and if isnull({?b}) or {?b} = '' then true else
{rptData.Second} like {?b}

....
```

Also tried like this:

```
if isnull({?a}) or {?a} = ''
then {rptData.First} = {rptData.First} else
{rptData.First} like {?a}

and ....
```

When I run the report, it loads expected data if all parameters are given. If I give first two/three parameters, it returns a blank report. Otherwise, it loads all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Use the HasValue() function to check if an **optional** parameter has value.

```
(HasValue({?a}) or {rptData.First} like "*" + {?a} + "*")
AND
(HasValue({?b}) or {rptData.Second} like "*" + {?b} + "*")
```